# @storybook/builder-vite is broken when using pnpm

Tags: vite, storybook, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

With npm or yarn this is not a problem, but when installing dependencies with pnpm nested dependencies of `@storybook/builder-vite` are not hoisted correctly resulting in this error:

```
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "@storybook/preview-web" from "../../../../../../virtual:/@storybook/builder-vite/vite-app.js".
```

I tried reinstalling dependencies, but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Adding `public-hoist-pattern[]=*storybook*` works on linux machines, but not on Windows for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix the problem based on this [answer in GitHub](https://github.com/storybookjs/builder-vite/issues/55#issuecomment-1273158147).

So adding .npmrc in the root directory with

```
public-hoist-pattern[]=*storybook*
```

resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In .npmrc this line will solve the issue too, special config line for pnpm because they have virtual store at node_modules/.pnpm. And this command will delete it and leave as with flatten node_modules like npm does.

```
node-linker=hoisted
```